# Reading websocket headers in C

Tags: c, networking, websocket, libpcap

so I wanted to read and decode websocket packets from a pcap file in C, i have tried some part of the code but the code doesn't show any output while running pcap_loop() , any help or suggestions would be great

The code used

````
struct websocketheader {
    int fin:1;
    u_int32_t res:3;
    uint32_t opcode:4;
    int mask:1;
    uint32_t payload_len:7; 
};
void websocket_handler(unsigned char *buffer, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
    struct websocketheader *wsh=(struct websocketheader*)(buffer +  sizeof(struct websocketheader));
    printf("FIN: %d",((wsh->fin)));
    printf("RSV1: %d",((wsh->res)));
    //printf("OPCODE: %d,"((wsh->opcode)));
    printf("MASK: %d",wsh->mask);

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(argv[1], errbuff);
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
    const u_char *data;
    u_int packetCount = 0;
    int returnValue=0;
    int total_packet_count=400;
    u_char *my_arguments = NULL;
    while (returnValue = (pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &data) >= 0))
    {
        printf("Packet # %i\n", ++packetCount);
        printf("Packet length: %d bytes\n", header->len);
        /*if (header->len != header->caplen)
            printf("Warning! Capture size different than packet size: %ld bytes\n", header->len);*/
        //printf("Epoch Time: %d:%d seconds\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec);
        for (u_int i=0; (i < header->caplen ) ; i++)
        {
            if ( (i % 16) == 0) printf("\n");
            printf("%.2x ", data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    //printf(packetCount);
    pcap_loop(pcap,packetCount,websocket_handler,NULL);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Oh no, you probably shouldn't use bitfields for this. There are subtle portability issues associated. Any answer would be solely dependent upon your implementation, and that's simply not C. You would need to tell us these details such as OS, compiler and CPU architecture. Alternatively, if you care about portability, you could use an array of bytes, shift and `&` to get the values, etc. That can be done portably.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the clarification. I am running it on MacOS Monterey and my compiler is the standard gcc compiler which comes with it

Comment: Ok well I recommend reading this because I suspect it may at least partially answer your question: http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfields.html

Comment: A small update, i have solved the issue. I tried to access the websocket data without reaching the payload, that was the main cause of error